# Gaelyk: returned truncated JSON

Tags: groovy, gaelyk, groovlet

I am "piping" a json feed (in some cases quite big) that is returned from an external service, to hide an access api-key to the client (the access key is the only available authentication system for that service).

I am using Gaelyk and I wrote this groovlet:

```
try {
    feed(params.topic)
} catch(Exception e) {
    redirect "/failure"
}

def feed(topic) {

    URL url = new URL("https://somewhere.com/$topic/<apikey>/feed")
    def restResponse = url.get()

    if (restResponse.responseCode == 200) {
        response.contentType = 'application/json'
        out << restResponse.text
    }
}
```

The only problem is that the "restResponse" is very big and the value returned by the groovlet is truncated. So I will get back a json like this:

```
[{"item":....},{"item":....},{"item":....},{"ite
```

How can I return the complete json without any truncation?

Comment: do you use routes output caching? this sometimes causes the problem even with HTML responses.

Comment: I put a 2 hours cache in routes but I have already tried without. The problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution and the problem was at the beginning (the URL content must be read as stream). So the content truncated it was not the output but the input:

```
def feed(topic) {
    URL url = "https://somewhere.com/$topic/<apikey>/feed".toURL()
    def restResponse = url.get()

    if (restResponse.responseCode == 200) {
        response.contentType = 'application/json'
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer()
        url.eachLine {
            sb << it
        }
        out << sb.toString()
    }
}
```